# How to set px.timeline tickvals?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-python

I created a gantt chart using px.timeline but for some reason when i use color function it changes the order of my data and to keep similar colors together...

y axis is string/ category values and i tried manually setting it with a list in the order i'd like the y axis to be graphed but nothing changed.

```
fig = px.timeline(dfGantt,
                  x_start = 'START',
                  x_end = 'END',
                  y = 'ident',
                  color = 'color',
                  )
fig.update_yaxes(tickvals = dfGantt['ident'],
                 type='category',
                 autorange="reversed",
                )
```

If i remove the color option it graphs as I'd like/expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

-using category_orders

```
fig = px.timeline(dfGantt,
                  x_start = 'START',
                  x_end = 'END',
                  y = 'ident',
                  color = 'color',
                  category_orders = {'ident':dfGantt['ident'].tolist()})

fig.update_yaxes(type='category',
                )
```